# Using Knockout for create and update on ViewModel

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, knockout.js

## HTML

```
<input type="button" id="addNewCert" value="Add New Certification" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: addCert"/>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody data-bind="foreach: certs">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" class="btn" value="Edit" data-bind="click: $parent.editCert" /></td>
            <td data-bind="text: certName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: certCode"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: description"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: certTypeName"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="selectedCert" data-bind="with: selectedCert">
    <div class="well">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <h6>Certification Name</h6>
                    <input type="text" id="CertificationName" data-bind="value: certName" style="width:100%;" />

                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <h6>Certification Code</h6>
                    <input type="text" id="CertificationCode" data-bind="value: certCode" style="width:50%;" />
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <h6>Description</h6>
                    <textarea ID="Description" data-bind="value: description" style="height:250px;width:480px;"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <h6>Certification Type</h6>
                    <select id="CertificationType" data-bind="options: $parent.availableCertTypes, optionsText: 'certTypeName', optionsValue: 'certTypeId', value: $parent.selectedCertType" style="width:100%;"></select>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Model

```
var Certification = function(data) {
    this.certId = ko.observable(data.CertificationId);
    this.certName = ko.observable(data.CertificationName);
    this.certCode = ko.observable(data.CertificationCode);
    this.description = ko.observable(data.Description);
    this.certTypeId = ko.observable(data.CertTypeId);
    this.certTypeName = ko.observable(data.CertTypeName);
    this.isEditing = ko.observable(false);
}
```

## ViewModel

```
var certViewModel = function (certs) {

    //Data
    var self = this;
    self.certs = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.editingCert = ko.observable(false);
    self.selectedCert = ko.observable();
    self.availableCertTypes = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.selectedCertType = ko.observable();

    self.editCert = function (cert) {
        self.editingCert(true);
        self.selectedCertType(cert.certTypeId());
        self.selectedCert(cert);
    }

    //Operations
    self.addCert = function () {
        self.selectedCert(new Certification());
    };

    self.removeCert = function (cert) {
        self.certs.remove(cert);
    };

    self.save = function () {

    };
}
```

I have a grid that is built out with Edit buttons for a list of Certifications, and when the edit button is clicked, the `with` binding works perfectly and shows me the correct information alongside the correctly selected option in the `<select>` tag.

### The Problem

But now what I am unsure of, is how do I let the button at the very top to "Add New Certification", generate a blank instance of the **Certification** model and show that same "edit" area?

I have found a ton of examples of doing edits for "inline" binding and edits, but that's not really what I'm going for as I'm trying to learn some of the ins and outs of Knockout and WebAPI to see if I can make a more client-side and AJAX driven version of some modules that are more based on WebForms.

Comment: just for your information, in your `Certification` object, you can save plenty of code by using [Knockout Mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) and all you do is `var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);`

Comment: That's the plan actually when I become more familiar with Knockout. For right now just going with what works and can fine-tune later :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your code gives an error because data is undefined when building the model.  It may have also been omitted but I don't see the `applyBindings` call here.

Here is a JSFiddle with it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/jzhh3/

The only changes are:

```
self.selectedCert(new Certification());
```

changed to

```
self.selectedCert(new Certification({}));
```

And the addition of `ko.applyBindings(certViewModel);`

Comment: Much simpler solution to the undefined error than mine. I'm not sure if I like either one though. This is one of the weird things about having Constructor like functions in JS. in C#, you'd just have two constructors on the class.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that the "addNewCert" function would error out due to having undefined properties.

Comment: That worked perfectly! What's the reasoning behind putting the braces in? Is it just because it would denote an empty JSON object?

Comment: The braces represent an empty object, which is distinctly not "undefined".  So when your Certification function is executing, data isn't undefined so it won't throw errors.  data.CertificationId is undefined though, so you won't get initial values which is exactly what you are after here.

Comment: @xdumaine I might be more inclined to do: if (!data) data = {};

At least it removes the responsibility from the caller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to call `new Certification()` without passing it an existing one, so in your constructor for Certification, check if data is null.

http://jsfiddle.net/QG3UZ/1/

```
var Certification = function(data) {
  this.certId = ko.observable(data ? data.CertificationId : null);
  this.certName = ko.observable(data ? data.CertificationName : null);
  this.certCode = ko.observable(data ? data.CertificationCode : null);
  this.description = ko.observable(data ? data.Description : null);
  this.certTypeId = ko.observable(data ? data.CertTypeId : null);
  this.certTypeName = ko.observable(data ? data.CertTypeName : null);
  this.isEditing = ko.observable(data ? false : true);
}
```